# Prove log(xy) = log x + log y

Tags: calculus, analysis

I would like some help with proving the following theorem, which I found in some lectures notes on analysis:

> If $x, y > 0$ then $\log(xy) = \log x + \log y$.
>
> Hint: Let $f(x) = \log(xy)$. What is $f'(x)$?

---

The hint is really throwing me off. If we define $\log(x)$ the way my book does, for $x > 0$, as

$$\log(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm dt$$

Then, following the hint, $$f(x) = \log(xy) = \int_{1}^{xy} \frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm dt$$

How would you go about finding $f'(x)$? The sheet just says $f'(x)$, but I assume it's with respect to $t$.

Comment: $\dfrac{d}{dx}\log (xy)=\dfrac 1x$, so $\log(xy)=\log x+C$. What is $C$? (Let $x=1$!)

Comment: Ah I see. Very simple. Could you point me to the calculus theorems which give you the first two steps?

Comment: It's not with respect to $t$! $t$ is a dummy variable. Do it with respect to $x$. (Hint: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus! Second hint: Chain rule.)

Comment: Yes, I'm looking at the FTC. But I'm still confused why $\frac{d}{dx} \log(xy) = \frac{1}{x}$. What happens to y?

Comment: $y$ is a constant, so that $(\log(xy))'=(xy)'/xy=y/xy=1/x$.

Comment: Oh, thanks for reminding me! The chain rule. I see what @columbus8myhw was saying now.

Answer (score 5):

Let me give another approach, using change of variables in the integral:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\log(xy)=\int_1^{xy}\frac{1}{t}\,dt &= \int_1^{x}\frac{1}{t}\,dt+\int_1^{xy}\frac{1}{t}\,dt-\int_1^{x}\frac{1}{t}\,dt\\
& = \int_1^{x}\frac{1}{t}\,dt + \int_x^{xy}\frac{1}{t}\,dt.
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, change variables $u=t/x$ in the second integral, and you are done.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{t=1}^{XY}\frac{dt}t=\int_{t=1}^X\frac{dt}t+\int_{t=X}^{XY}\frac{dt}t=\int_{t=1}^X\frac{dt}t+\int_{u=1}^Y\frac{du}u,$$
by the change of variable $t=Xu$, such that $\dfrac{dt}t=\dfrac{du}u$.

Comment: It almost looks like you are factoring an x out of the integral, and I'm not well-versed enough with calculus to know why this is okay.

Comment: No, I am decomposing the integration interval in two, and using the given change of variable in the second subinterval.

Comment: Right. I just don't see how $\int_{X}^{XY} \frac{dt}{t} = \int_{1}^{Y} \frac{du}{u}$ for your substitution of u.

Comment: $t$ from $X$ to $XY$ is $u$ from $1$ to $Y$, since $t=Xu$.